# finding pivot point of two 3D transformations

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I need to find out what the degrees of freedom are between two arbitrary geometries that may be linked to eachother. for instance a hinge consisting of two parts. I can simulate the motion of the two parts, and I figured that if I fix one of the parts in place, i can deduce what the axes and point of rotation is for the second moving part is from the transformation in each timestep.

I run into some difficulties calculating this (my vector algebra is ok, my (numpy) math skills less so)

How I see it is I have two 4x4 transformation matrices for each timestep, the previous position/orientation of the moving part (A) and the current position/orientation (A')

then the point of rotation can be found by by calculating the transformation matrix B that transforms A into A' which is I believe

B = inverse(A) * A'

and then find the point that does not change under transformation by B:

x = Bx

Is my thinking correct and if so, how do I solve this equation?

Comment: Usually a rigid transformation can be written as a rotation followed by a translation, i.e. P' = R.P + T (R is a 2x2 matrix, T a vector, P, P' a point before and after). Using homogeneous coordinates, you can indeed pack that in a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: I'm talking about 4x4 transformation matrices that combine rotation and translation. i'll update my Q

Comment: You should specify 3D then.